# Extjs 4 Mvc Application to Production

Tags: extjs4, extjs, extjs-mvc

i have created a extjs4 MVC application with asp.net.
The application run without any errors with ext-all-debug.js file in development environment.

Now when i used sencha sdk 1.2.3 to generate minified js files (successfully generated app-all.js & all-classes.js).

But when i run in production these generated files it show dependencies errors.

like `Ext.create('Fleet.view.gadgets.ux.GridPrinter')` doesn't exist. etc

Can any body help me how to orginized my code so sencha sdk tool minified all my source.js file into the production app-all.js file.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Couple things to look for:

1. Check app-classes.js - this is your application in non-minified form. Do you see your class there?
2. Make sure you have all `requires: []` definitions. For example you should have `requires: [ 'Fleet.view.gadgets.ux.GridPrinter']` in the controller that uses this view. Or you can define it like this `views: ['gadgets.ux.GridPrinter']`. These properties are basically indicators for parser to go and grab required classes as well.